# How to create custom Layout?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

In my apps i want to display images and text in three ways

1. `ListView`
2. `GridView`
3. `FullScreen`

i have 500+ images and text that i parse using `JSON` and store into `SQLite`.

I know how to create `ListView` & `GridView` but problem is I don't know how to create the custom layout.

I have image but due to my low reputation i am not able to post image.

I try to explain what i need.

I need custom fullscreen layout that has 2 buttons, one on the left and other on the right and between those 2 buttons I need `Imageview` that display the fullscreen image.

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you read the official documentation to create [XML Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) in Android ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library, as it has all the modes you need. It also supports caching and lazy load, which you will definitely need on 500 images.

Comment: @Sir David i need exactly what you give me. but the problem is its so hard to implement into my project. is it possible to customise the project

Comment: It has sample application to refer to. Believe me, it's worth it. You will spend less time then writing everything from scratch (I've been through this and I'm not too good in Android development).